# How to print array in typescript which includes the argument passed through the function?

Tags: typescript

I am new to type script i need help with a query. if I pass the following argument:

- line("") it should return [0,""]
- line("TypeScript") it should return [0,"Typescript"]

I've written the following code however every time I run it says maximum stack size called.

```
function line(s: string) : [number, string] 
{
    return line("") ? [0,""]:[0,s]
}
```

Comment: You have no base condition in your recursive function call!

Comment: this function will call itself infinitely, thereby filling the callstack to its max.

Comment: `return [0,s]` should do what you want

Comment: Your whole function can be re written as `function line(s: string): [number, string] { return [0, s] }` !!! it doesn't have any logic.